# System.AggregateException exception when using with Parallel.Invoke()

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, wmi

I am trying to run 2 exe in Parallel using `Parallel.Invoke()`
Both the exe is trying to access the same Database (but different tables). Also, the exe's will run in two different servers.
I am using WMI with C# to start the batch file (which will invoke the other exe file) in the remote server.

```
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
                RunInParallel();
            },
            () =>
            {
                InvokeModule("EmiCalculator.exe");
            } 
            );

void RunInParallel()
{
                var connoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
                var managementScope = new ManagementScope
                    (String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", REMOTE_COMPUTER), connoptions);
                var wmiProc = new ManagementClass(managementScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
                string commandLineInput = @"\\win-server1\D$\Data\Run.bat";
                var processToRun = new[] { commandLineInput };
                wmiProc.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun);
}
```

Run.bat is calling SalaryCalculator.exe

Both the exe are having a configuration file with ConnectionString as below.

```
<add name="CONN" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER1-LAB1;Initial Catalog=Loan;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

When running, the exe in remote machine is getting crashed and throwing below exception :

```
Application: SalaryCalculator.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AggregateException
Stack:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(System.Threading.Tasks.Task[], Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(System.Threading.Tasks.Task[], Int32)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(System.Threading.Tasks.Task[])
```

NOTE: If I run the batch file after connecting to remote machine, it is working perfectly. It is only throwing error when using with `Parallel.Invoke()`

How can I proceed here ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Aron for your comment. However, I was able to make this work. Please find my answer below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to make this work. The issue was connection string as Integrated Secuity was mentioned.
I just changed the connectionstring to use `SQL server authentication` instead of Windows authentication. And it worked fine.

```
< add name="CONN" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER1-LAB1;Initial Catalog=Loan;User Id=sa;Password=xxxx12345678" />
```